# Bootstrap Tab and AJAX Function misfunction

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a simple tab and a button to activate one of the tab to bypass the pills.

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs hide" role="tablist" id="myTab">
        <li role="presentation" ><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="aaa"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="home">1</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">2</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">3</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">4</div>
    </div>
```

and some javascript

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
 $(this).tab('show')
 })
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnn').click( function() {
                   $('#myTab a[href="#messages"]').tab('show');
            });
        });
```

however when i use this code in my real page, the button does not function anymore, because i have a slider that does an immediate ajax call. If I remove the first AJAX call it works. But as you imagine, i actually need that ajax call :)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
  value:10,
  min: 0,
  max: 12,
  step: 1,
  range: "min",
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + " mois");
  },
  change: function(event, ui) {
        // when the user change the slider
    },
  create : function(event, ui) {
      var request = $.ajax({
        url: "Ajax_livret.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : 'duree=' + 10,           
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#result").html(msg);         
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });            

  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "Ajax_livret.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : 'duree=' + ui.value,         
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#result").html(msg);         
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });            
   },

});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider('value') + " mois");

  });



   </script>
```

Anyone has an idea why this is occurring and how to fix it?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem !

I was loading Jquery again in my ajax file hence causing problems. I hope my answer will help people !